# IPython with Jupyter

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

I have this problem with initiate Jupyter and try use.
Someone can help me?

Python 3.7.2

```
[IPKernelApp] ERROR | Failed to load connection file: 'C:\\Users\\epinheiro\\App
Data\\Roaming\\jupyter\\runtime\\kernel-3fbbe97a-8dd5-4e15-8db1-2e7cef385b58.jso
n'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\epinheiro\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packa
ges\ipykernel\kernelapp.py", line 224, in init_connection_file
    self.load_connection_file()
  File "c:\users\epinheiro\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packa
ges\jupyter_client\connect.py", line 494, in load_connection_file
    info = json.load(f)
AttributeError: module 'json' has no attribute 'load'
[W 12:14:08.636 NotebookApp] KernelRestarter: restart failed
[W 12:14:08.636 NotebookApp] Kernel 3fbbe97a-8dd5-4e15-8db1-2e7cef385b58 died, r
emoving from map.
[W 12:14:53.844 NotebookApp] Timeout waiting for kernel_info reply from 3fbbe97a
-8dd5-4e15-8db1-2e7cef385b58
[E 12:14:53.847 NotebookApp] Error opening stream: HTTP 404: Not Found (Kernel d
oes not exist: 3fbbe97a-8dd5-4e15-8db1-2e7cef385b58)
```

Comment: Do you have by any chance a file called `json.py` in your current working directory?

Comment: you are trying to import the builtin module called "json" and somewhere in your current working directory json.py also present. If it present then rename the file